# What do we do with plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

There are many answers here which, due to the fact we don't like link only answers, are copies from other websites.

We can include a link to the source. Without this link, it's plagiarism. I'm also unsure as to where we stand in regards to copy right... stuff!

[Is it possible to bcc someone on every email sent from a list in owa](https://superuser.com/questions/1238351/is-it-possible-to-bcc-someone-on-every-email-sent-from-a-list-in-owa) which is (as per my comment in that post) a copy and paste. The OP has clearly taken time to provide a good quality answer but, it's still plagerism at this stage. I also am not 100% certain he/she copied from the link I cite as I've not checked every word/line of code etc so **they** need to provide the link (otherwise I could fix myself).

How do we handle plagiarism posts?

Answer (score 4):

#### How do we handle plagiarism posts?

First, please make sure you have read [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

Summary:

- Double check
- Edit or Flag
- Educate the OP

If you think a post consists of plagiarised text and images and is not correctly attributed then you should flag for moderator attention, mention your concerns, and provide a link to where the material came from.

A moderator will handle it as appropriate.

The rules regarding this are quite specific so you can also leave a comment for the OP to adjust his answer.

[How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing):

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Super User) make sure you do all of
>   the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author
>
> ...
>
> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
>   words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to
>   the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link
>   to it.

Comment: This x2000 times.  Plagarism is unacceptable.  There isn't any justification for it.  It's also exactly the type of thing that a patent troll type personality would sue StackExchange for.  So it must be nuked for the high heavens.